# I want to change the color, size and style of the font in footer Apache poi XWPF

Tags: java, ms-word, footer, xwpf

I want to change the color, size and style of the font in footer Apache poi XWPF

```
FileInputStream finStream = new FileInputStream(pathToWorkbook);
             XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(finStream);
             
             docx
                .createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT)
                .createParagraph()
                .createRun()
                .setText("FOOTER");
```

or

```
XWPFParagraph[] pars;

                CTP ctP = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
                CTText t = ctP.addNewR().addNewT();
                pars = new XWPFParagraph[1];

                XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy hfPolicy = doc.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

                ctP = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
                t = ctP.addNewR().addNewT();
                // footer text
                t.setStringValue("Sample Footer Text");

                pars[0] = new XWPFParagraph(ctP, doc);
                hfPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, pars);
```

Please help, if you can :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried many solutions until it was solved.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to help others with the same or a similar question.